# Why does `kill -0` return success on a non-existent process?

Tags: kill, process-management

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, (Jammy Jellyfish).

```
$ ps -p 1635
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
$ kill -0 1635 ; echo $?
0
$ type kill
kill is a shell builtin
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
5.1.16(1)-release
$ mount|grep proc
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
```

I'd expect `kill -0` to return `bash: kill: (1635) - No such process`.

*Update 1*

```
ps -eLf | awk 'NR == 1 || /1635/'
 PID    PPID     LWP  C NLWP STIME TTY          TIME CMD
1632    1091    1635  0    9 13:07 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/evolution-calendar-factory
```

Comment: Do you administer this system? Have you set `hidepid` when mounting `procfs`?

Comment: Yes I administer the system. I haven’t done anything special to procfs.

Comment: What's the output from `which kill`?

Comment: @AndrewHenle make that `type kill` - `kill` is probably going to be the built-in `kill`, but might be a function or alias, and `which` won't help with any of those cases.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Question updated.

Comment: I can't reproduce this in the `ubuntu:22.04` Dockerhub Docker container.

Comment: Can you repeat and is the result the same each time? Your `ps` and your `kill` acted at different moments, a process with PID 1635 may have appeared in between.

Comment: It's consistent. I tried 1636 as well, same behavior.

Comment: Can you pastebin `/tmp/log` after `strace -o /tmp/log bash -c 'kill -0 1635'`?

Comment: 1635 sounds like an oddly specific PID to test against. How did you pick that one? Guess: you have a _thread_ with that PID, and `ps` doesn't show those by default. See what `ps -eLf | awk 'NR == 1 || /1635/'` shows you? (In case you're wondering, that AWK is pretty much the same as `grep 1635`, except it also prints the first record(line), i.e. the header.)

Comment: @ilkkachu Question updated. Indeed, seems that 1635 is a light weight process. Please post your comment as an answer, which I'll accept.

Comment: @ilkkachu do post an answer